# iCloud just display the photos and do not download them as the iPhone does

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, storage, photos.app

I've always been an iPhone user, however, I just recently bought my first MacBook Pro and one of the things that made me upset was iCloud, it downloaded all my photos and videos to the device, I'd like it to do as it is on the iPhone only displays the photo, however, it only downloads it when we open it. It's possible?

PS: I researched a little bit about, however, I did not find anything: /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photos is designed to either download every photo to your Mac when using iCloud Photo Library  or "Optimize Mac storage" which stores fewer photos on your Mac based on the amount of space you have.  [image: Photos > Preferences > iCloud]